# Signalr: Connection Limitation from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, signalr

See the following sentences from getting started tutorial:

"....Note that if a client operating system is used, such as for development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed, which will be reached very quickly since connections are transient, frequently re-established, and are not disposed immediately upon no longer being used. IIS Express should be used on client operating systems.

Also note that for SignalR to use WebSocket, IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express must be used, the server must be using Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, or later, and WebSocket must be enabled in IIS. For information on how to enable WebSocket in IIS, see IIS 8.0 WebSocket Protocol Support."

**Does it means that if I had deploy my application with Signalr on a windows 7 or windows 8 with IIS, that there is a limit of 10 connections? Are 10 connection per application or all applications together? Is there a possibility to "upgrad" to more connections?**

**How many connection do I have on windows 7 embedded?**

**How many connection do I have on windows server?**

Comment: Just curious, why would you be deploying your application to Windows 7 or Windows 8? Shouldn't you just be doing development on it? The max concurrent connection limit is through IIS or Cassini (Visual Studio) but is not imposed when using IIS Express. So, for dev purposes you should be running against IIS Express if you want to use more than 10 concurrent connections.

Comment: Maybe because the there is an existing system and windows server is much more expensive.